# Where does Hive store data on the file system?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have managed to install and use Hadoop HDFS and Hive and I am able to fetch and insert data into Hive using Talend.

My problem is that when ever we create a table from Talend (using the Apache distribution) it is creating it in Hive but I am unable to see the same in the Hive database.

Where are these tables being created on the file system?

Answer (score 0):

Actually hive is work on top of the hadoop mean using the hdfs for storage or can be use another file system.

if your hive use file system as hdfs then

go to terminal where you hadoop installed.

```
hadoop dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hadoop dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse` for Hive managed tables
If you create tables with `external` keyword, You should give the path to create the table.so table will be created in the given path and can be seen with `hadoop dfs -ls <path-to-given-directory>`
Hope it helps.